# How can I parse XML of having multiple Nodes with same name and show in different controller?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, xmlnode

See the XML below

http://sosmoths.com/.xml/moths.xml

This XML having multiple images name, I have to show the different title(There are four title) in their respective Controller.
I have 4 controller, and have to show each moth value in different Controller, along with their multiple images values, how can I do it?

I can make single object of should I make four objects?

I am a bit confused in it, please help me.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. When you derive a specific data you can trigger a protocol call of a particular viewController and same way for the other three when their data is derived. So use of Protocol can solve your problem.

Comment: I tried Bhatt, but a bit confused, can you give me a bit idea by giving code, it is tableview with four rows, and each row will show respective moth,

Comment: I added all code after parsing your url Add this code to your project: http://pastebin.com/GsBC3ZuR

Comment: Check the output, the description is not complete data, because foundCharacter methods executes too many time within one description node, as per its behaviour, same problem with Ron answer

Comment: okay now try http://pastebin.com/GsBC3ZuR it's give approx 90 % nearest output just make little changes to make it 100 % :)

Comment: I have done it by appendString, but there is one tiny problem, it can't recognize the special characters , so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This XML having multiple images name, I have to show the different
>   title(There are four title) in their respective Controller. I have 4
>   controller, and have to show each moth value in different Controller,
>   along with their multiple images values, how can I do it?

This sounds less like an XML parsing problem and more like an app architecture problem.

That XML basically describes some data and said data would typically be represented by objects in your application.  You could go with a CoreData based solution whereby you parse the XML into a local CoreData store (in memory or on disk, matters not) and then display the managed objects as per usual.

Or, assuming that is representative of a typical set of data, you could parse it into your own hand rolled objects (or, even, dictionaries and arrays), then display from there.

There are dozens of questions about parsing XML on SO (and via Google).

The second part of your question hasn't been addressed.  Basically, you need to properly layer your app into the model-view-controller pattern.   Your model layer would parse the XML and create an object graph that represents the data.   Each controller would have a reference to that single model.

This will work fine as long as your app is read only.  If the various controllers are expected to also edit the object graph, then it'll need to be a bit more complex in that you'll have to deal with change propagation (this is where CoreData shines;  it makes change management, propagation, validation, and undo relatively straightforward).

Answer (score 0):

With TBXML you can easily parse the xml and it will convert it into objects to use:

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html

and libxml2 is also that you can use easily to parse.

Comment: I havn't used it before, can you give me idea to use such xml using TBXML,

Comment: The problem is having multipletag with one name, so the same thing, I can't found my answer even via TBXML

Comment: Go ahead and use the libxml2, once you follow it and usign correctly to aprse...it will generate the array of the nodes having the same name. The only thing is to try and you will get the solution from libxml2 only. Even I have the same parallel node like <employees><employee></employee><employee></employee></employees> but it will generate the array of employee once you parse with the help of libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this it worked properly       
  -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
            NSLog(@"%@",elementName);
            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moths"]){
                mytblarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            } else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moth"]){
                tmpdic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            }
            else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]){
                imgArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            }

        }

        -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

            if(tmpstr!=nil && [tmpstr retainCount]>0){ [tmpstr release]; tmpstr=nil; }
            tmpstr=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:string];

        }

        -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

            if([elementName isEqualToString:@"moth"]){
                [mytblarray addObject:tmpdic];
                [tmpdic release];
            }if([elementName isEqualToString:@"images"]){
                [tmpdic setValue:imgArray forKey:elementName];
            }
            else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"image"]){
                [imgArray addObject:tmpstr];        
            }
            else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"id"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]||[elementName isEqualToString:@"description"]){
                [tmpdic setValue:tmpstr forKey:elementName];
            }

        }

        -(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
            NSLog(@"%@",[imgArray description]);
            NSLog(@"%@",[mytblarray description]);
        }
        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //get value like it
        NSString *cellValue = [[mytblarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"id"];
    }
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //get value like it

            NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:
    [mytblarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
```

Comment: The use of retainCount in that code is meaningless and raises suspicions that the rest of it may be broken, too.

Comment: The better way was to give answer of question, if you know better @bbum

Comment: Didn't have time when I saw this.  Wanted to make sure this code wasn't blindly copy/pasted as it has some serious issues.

Comment: @bbum if u know any better way please help me.because i use same method